# How can I use gulp-imagemin to replace the original file

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I need to setup a `gulp` task to optimize the image files in a directory, but since this is an existing site, I cannot change the output directory. In other words, I need the optimized image to *replace* the existing image.

I have googled around, and read the documentation for `gulp-imagemin`, and even tried to do it using the shell, to no avail.

There *must* be a way to do this, but so far, I have found no evidence of how to do so on the internet. I'm hoping the good people of SO can help me out in this regard :)

Here's my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngcrush = require('imagemin-pngcrush');

var paths = {
  files: './webroot/sites/files/**',
  filesDest: './webroot/sites/files',
};

gulp.task('files', function() {
  'use strict';

  // Minify all images
  return gulp.src(paths.files, {base: './webroot/sites/files'})
    .pipe(imagemin({
    progressive: true,
    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
    use: [pngcrush()]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.filesDest));
});

gulp.task('default', ['files']);
```

Comment: I managed to make it work on my station using your gulpfile as it is. Did you check the chmod of your images? They could be read only.

Comment: You're right @Delapouite, it is working! I was using `du -sh` to track the decrease, which wasn't granular enough to see a change. If I just use `du -s`, I see the decrease. Thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code, as Delapouite said, is working, I was simply checking for it incorrectly.